# BluetoothSocket.isConnected issue

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have created an Android Application in that if my Android has a Bluetooth connection to my computer and I power down my computer, isConnected still returns true. Anyone know if this can be fixed?

I'm not sure if there's a Bluetooth heartbeat or not.

Comment: why don't you keep a broadcast receiver with BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED and BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
    IntentFilter connectivityFilter = new IntentFilter();
    connectivityFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    connectivityFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    registerReceiver(bluetoothModeCheckingReceiver, connectivityFilter);



 private final BroadcastReceiver bluetoothModeCheckingReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)) {
            // to do
        } else if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)) {
           //  to do
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Got solution! Thanks!